# Gibbs sampling equation for LDA

Tags: probability, sampling, dirichlet-series, gibbs-measure

I don't understand what the w' means in the last derivation.

[image]

Here is the link for the paper: https://coli-saar.github.io/cl19/materials/darling-lda.pdf